# Xamarin Error, following tutorial, dependencies issues for days

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Using Visual Studio 2017, Community Edition.

I'm doing the tutorial (/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) for Xamarin and I'm getting a similar error, whenever I try to update any of the Android packages.  If I try to update Xamarin.Androix.Support.Vector.Drawable, I get the following error message:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable 25.4.0.2' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 23.3.0 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable (= 23.3.0)'.         0

I went to the Android SDK manager and updated everything I could find there, still no luck.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first upgrade `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`. If it's an option, you could just upgrade ALL packages in one shoot using `update` option from `Packages` context menu on the solution explorer.

Comment: When I click on update for the .Support.v7.AppCompat, I get the same error: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.270 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)'.   0 
"

Comment: That's because there is a chain of upgrades you need to do. Can't you just tell visual studio to upgrade all? After all, you're just running a sample project.

Comment: If I do update all (Select all packages), I get the same error and it fails on the first thing it tries to update.

Comment: What is your configuration for the following settings? https://screencast.com/t/DEHcnlyo4dwk and https://screencast.com/t/vFybqNUU